# Solr storage handling

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud, solrconfig

I have six node solr cluster and every node having 200GB of storage, we created one collection with two shards.

I like to know what will happen if my document reached 400GB (node1-200GB,node-2 200GB) ? is solr automatically use another free node from my cluster ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If my document reached 400GB (node1-200GB,node-2 200GB) ?

Ans: I am not sure about what exacly error you may get, however in production you should try not to face this situation. To avoid/handle such scenarios we have [monitoring/autoscaling triggers](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/solrcloud-autoscaling-triggers.html) apis.

2. Is solr automatically use another free node from my cluster ?

Ans: No, Extra shards will not be added automatically. However whenever you observe that search is getting slow or if solr is crossing physical limitations of machines then you should go for [splitShard](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/collections-api.html#splitshard) .

So ultimately you can handle this with autscaling triggers. That is you can set [autscaling triggers](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/solrcloud-autoscaling-triggers.html) to identify whether a shard is crossing specified limits about the number of document or size of the index etc. Once this limits reaches this trigger can call [splitShard](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/collections-api.html#splitshard)

[This link](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/solrcloud-autoscaling-triggers.html#index-size-trigger) mentions

> This trigger can be used for monitoring the size of collection shards,
>   measured either by the number of documents in a shard or the physical
>   size of the shard’s index in bytes.
>
> When either of the upper thresholds is exceeded the trigger will
>   generate an event with a (configurable) requested operation to perform
>   on the offending shards - by default this is a SPLITSHARD operation.